# How to access a Stimulus JS controller method from inside a nested function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have a Stimulus controller inside which I have a setSegments function and then this code in the connect() method:

```
connect() {
        const options = {
            overview: {
                container: document.getElementById('overview-container'),
                waveformColor: 'blue',
            },
            mediaElement: document.querySelector('audio'),
            dataUri: {
                arraybuffer: document.getElementById('normal-audio-button').dataset.waveform
            },
            emitCueEvents: true,
        };

        Peaks.init(options, function (err, peaks) {
            window.instance = peaks;
            window.speed = "normal";
            setSegments()
            instance.on('segments.enter', function (segment) {
                const segmentCard = document.getElementById(segment.id)
                segmentCard.focus({preventScroll: true})
                window.currentSegment = segment
            });
        });

    }

setSegments() {

  alert("segment set up)

}
```

I'm tryng to call setSegments() inside the Peaks.init function but it doesn't work because of the function's scope. I'm just not sure how to get around this. I tried calling this.setSegments() instead but it doesn't help.

What's the correct way of accessing the function in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `this` is a bit confusing when working with JavaScript, however a way to think about it that it is the current context.

For example, when your code is running in the browser console or not in another function `this` is the global `window` object. When you are directly in the controller's `connect` method `this` is the controller's instance.

However, when you pass a function to `Peaks.init` that function creates it's own new context where `this` is the function's context and no longer the controller instance.

There are three common workarounds to calling `this.setSegments`;

### 1. Set a variable that is outside the function scope

As per your solution, `const setSegments = this.setSegments;` works because you are creating a reference outside the function scope and functions have access to this.

```
connect() {
        const options = {}: // ... Options
        // this is the controller's instance
        const setSegments = this setSegments;

        Peaks.init(options, function (err, peaks) {
            // this is the peaks init handler context
            window.instance = peaks;
            // this.setSegments(): - will not work
           setSegments();
            instance.on('segments.enter', function (segment) {
                // this is the event (usually)
            });
        });

    }
```

### 2. Use bind to override the function's`this`

You can pull your function out to a variable and then add `.bind(this)` to it so that when the function is called it will use the this from the controller instance instead.

```
connect() {
        const options = {}: // ... Options
        // this is the controller's instance
       const myFunction = function (err, peaks) {
            // this is the BOUND this provided by the bind command and will be the controller's instance
            window.instance = peaks;
            this.setSegments():
            instance.on('segments.enter', function (segment) {
                // this is the event (usually)
            });
        };
        myFunction.bind(this);

        Peaks.init(options, myFunction);

    }
```

### 3. Use an arrow function (easiest)

You should be able to use an arrow function in modern browsers or if you have a build tool running it may transpiled this for older browsers.

Instead of `function() {}` you use `() => {}` and it grabs the `this` from the parent function context instead.

```
connect() {
        const options = {}: // ... Options
        // this is the controller's instance

        Peaks.init(options, (err, peaks) => {
            // this is now the controller's instance and NOT the peak handler context
            window.instance = peaks;
            this.setSegments():
            instance.on('segments.enter', function (segment) {
                // this is the event (usually) and is NOT the controller instance as arrow function not used here.
            });
        });

    }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but adding the following right after the beginning of the connect method did the trick:

```
let setSegments = this.setSegments
```